# Match all hosts except one, regex

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, traefik

Having hard time with regex, any help is much appreciated!

Traefik + docker-swarm. Goal is to have one specific failback service, which should receive  any requests that didn't much main domain.

What I tried:

`traefik.frontend.rule=HostRegexp:{all:^((?!mydomain.com).)*$$}`

and

`traefik.frontend.rule=HostRegexp:all:^((?!mydomain.com).)*$$`

`traefik.frontend.rule=HostRegexp:^((?!mydomain.com).)*$$`

This should match all requests to any hosts besides `*.mydomain.com`, but it doesn't work, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with any of the techs you are using but this works on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/s06Ohe/4):

```
^(.+\.mydomain\.com)$
```

Or the opposite might be what you want, which on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Cvi9VW/1) looks like this:

```
^((?!\.mydomain\.com).)*$
```

Note this last regex does not work on the `golang` flavor of regex. If this works depends on which flavor of regex the techs you are using apply.

You can try different flavors with Regex101.